# Why this dockpanel doesn't dock its child correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this xaml:

```
 <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Left"  IsExpanded="True">
      <Expander.Header>
         <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" >
              <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
              <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="10" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}" cal:Message.Attach="RemoveFromList($dataContext)">
               </Button>
           </DockPanel>
      </Expander.Header>  
</Expander>
```

But when it shows, I am getting the button on left just next to textblock.

Why it is not dcoked to right?

Comment: Why you want to place your DockPanel inside Expander's header ?
Works as desired when hosted as expander's child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t see docking problem here, the button is on the right edge of `DockPanel`. It`s just that `DockPanel` has minimal required width, so all contents are cramped together. You can add some background to help you see the dimensions.

```
<Grid Background="Yellow">
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsExpanded="True">
          <Expander.Header>
             <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Background="Red" Width="200">
                  <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                  <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="10" />
               </DockPanel>
          </Expander.Header>  
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Note that I added `Width` setting to inner `DockPanel` to show that `Button` is on far right side.